# Stopping SpringBatch jobs started from the command line

Tags: spring-batch

Spring Batch jobs can be started from the commandline by telling the JVM to run CommandLineJobRunner. According to [the JavaDoc](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/launch/support/CommandLineJobRunner.html), running the same command with the added parameter of `-stop` will stop the Job:

> The arguments to this class can be provided on the command line
>   (separated by spaces), or through stdin (separated by new line). They
>   are as follows:
>
> jobPath jobIdentifier (jobParameters)* The command line options are as
>   follows
>
> - `jobPath`: the xml application context containing a Job
> - `-restart`: (optional) to restart the last failed execution
> - `-stop`: (optional) to stop a running execution
> - `-abandon`: (optional) to abandon a stopped execution
> - `-next`: (optional) to start the next in a sequence according to the JobParametersIncrementer in the Job jobIdentifier: the name of the job or the id of a job execution (for -stop, -abandon or -restart).
> - `jobParameters`: 0 to many parameters that will be used to launch a job specified in the form of key=value pairs.

However, on the JavaDoc for the main() method the -stop parameter is not specified. Looking through the code on docjar.com I can't see any use of the -stop parameter where I would expect it to be.

I suspect that it is possible to stop a batch that has been started from the command line but only if the batches being run are backed by a non-transient `jobRepository`? If running a batch on the command line that only stores its data in HSQL (ie in memory) there is no way to stop the job other than `CTRL-C` etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

stop command is implemented, see [source for CommandLineJobRunner](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-batch/blob/master/spring-batch-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/core/launch/support/CommandLineJobRunner.java), line 300+

```
        if (opts.contains("-stop")) {
            List<JobExecution> jobExecutions = getRunningJobExecutions(jobIdentifier);
            if (jobExecutions == null) {
                throw new JobExecutionNotRunningException("No running execution found for job=" + jobIdentifier);
            }
            for (JobExecution jobExecution : jobExecutions) {
                jobExecution.setStatus(BatchStatus.STOPPING);
                jobRepository.update(jobExecution);
            }
            return exitCodeMapper.intValue(ExitStatus.COMPLETED.getExitCode());
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

The `stop` switch will work, but it will only stop the job after the currently executing step completes. It won't kill the job immediately.